# What's the form of the modal "must" in the past or future?

Tags: modal-verbs

I know that modals normally don't have past form, but sometimes they have an other way or equivalent verb to cope and to express them in past tense or future tense. For example:

> can becomes could in past tense and for the future we use "will be able to...".

My question now is about the modal "**must**", how can I apply with equivalents for the past and future?

For example:

> You **must** listen to this recording.

Comment: I just found the answer by a friend. Anyway, I'll leave the question here for others who'll seek this question too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You must listen to this recording.

**For past*:**

had to = must to

> You **had to** listen to this recording.

- N.b. There's an archaic and very rare past form of "must": [mote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mote#Etymology_2). It's not common in usage.

**For future:**

will have to = must to

> You **will have to** listen to this recording.

Comment: Actually, do not be surprised that **must** can be found as past tense - but quite rarely, so for active use I strongly agree to recommend learners use forms of **have to**.

Comment: While valid substitutes, these are alternative phrases, not transformations of the word "must." They are transformations of the phrase, "have to." I'm not sure there is an actual form of "must" for these tenses.